# Execute shell script on cygwin from Python

Tags: cygwin, python-3.4

I want to execute a shell script, on cygwin from Python. The shell script is creating a file as an output.

I tried

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir(r"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\ ")
cmd = ["bash", "-c", 'cd /<path for the script>; ./test.sh']
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: `os.chdir(r"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\ ")` contains a space. What is your error?

Comment: are you using the python of cygwin or the windows one?

Comment: it gives error as grep command not found, i am using grep in the first line of the shell script

Comment: no i am using python of windows.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have a script and some commands work and some others like "cp", "sed" doesn't

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
import os, subprocess
os.chdir(r"C:\cygwin64\bin")
cmd = ["bash", "-c", "cd $HOME; pwd; exit"]
ret = subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Comment: A description, why this solves the problem, greatly improves your answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I have tried with a script that includes commands like cp or sed and it doesn't work. But there are other commands in the same script, like test, do, for, echo and works fine. Any idea?